# Browser caching static files?

Tags: google-chrome, static-files

When I use static files that are served by a backend(Django/Node). I noticed that even if I delete the static files from the backend static folder. The static icons or images will still display even after I restart the server as long as I am serving to the same localhost port.

For example I deleted the following html:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">`

And the tab icon still displays as long as I serve to the same `localhost:port`.

- Why is this happening?
- And how do I disable it?

Comment: it was just a cache. It may disappear in few days or you can do hard refresh : cmd + shift + R ( ctr + shift + R on window) and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser caches static files. When testing, it's useful to disable the  cache. In chrome, go to developer tools, click on the Network tab, then check "Disable cache".

Comment: Is there a way to set this up through command line options or config file?

Answer (score 0):

When working with sites for customers, adding a version to the static content file path is required.

For example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/ver-1/favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/ver-2/favicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/ver-3/favicon.png">
```

Or even:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon-2017-11NOV-08.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon-2017-12DEC-25.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon-2018-01JAN-01.png">
```

**Using these, or similar methods, means there is no need to modify browser settings on anyone's computer.**

Changing the file name will force all browsers to retrieve the new file from the server, and the browser cache for the old file is ignored completely.